# Why starting any GNOME based program over SSH takes about 30 seconds?

Tags: gnome, ssh, remote

GNOME based programs always take about 30 seconds to start over SSH. Even simplest ones, like `gnome-calculator`. After said programs start, they run absulutely fine. I am starting SSH session using `ssh <user>@<host> -YC` command. I've tried checking CPU usage during this wait period, but there is nothing out of ordinary. Network bandwidth usage doesn't seem to be excessive either (in the range of 0.2 to 2 KiB/s).

I am using my Ubuntu 19.10 machine over SSH a lot and it's quite a problem for me. I've seen this problem in earlier Ubuntu versions as well.

EDIT: I've found that this delay happens when call to `g_application_run()` is made. Running `strace` explains that delay time. Last syscall before that delay is `poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000)`. 25000 being timeout in millisecons. All affected programs stall at this particular syscall. File descriptor 11 is created using `eventfd2(0, EFD_CLOEXEC|EFD_NONBLOCK)`. All this means that program is waiting for some kind of event that never happens. But what can it be and what can cause it?

Comment: Hi, this is not an issue specific to Ubuntu, its due to X11 forwarding being inefficient for modern use. https://superuser.com/questions/1217280/why-is-x11-forwarding-so-inefficient answers your question nicely in terms of why its slow. Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187415/why-is-firefox-so-slow-over-ssh provides some options for helping speed things up.

Comment: I don't think that this is the same problem since even complex programs like QtCreator or Firefox launch immediately. Sure there is some latency and bandwidth limitations, but these are to be expected. I've also tried KDE programs. They run fine.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is due to the DISPLAY environment variable not being propagated to a local service called "xdg-desktop-portal-gtk". If it fails to start, each gnome application will try to start it during startup, wait for it to come up, then timeout after ~25s when it fails.

You can fix this manually by doing this after logging in. First, update the environment for dbus processes:

$ dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

Then start the service:

$ systemctl --user start xdg-desktop-portal-gtk

Now startup should be fast again.

If someone knows the best/most elegant way to do this automagically for every using logging in to a remote system I'd like to know about it.

Comment: This could be it but I can't test this solution since I am not using Ubuntu on any of my machines anymore. If enough people upvote this answer I am going to accept it.

Comment: The strace data matches exactly with what I found. Also, we have this on CentOS machines; the issue is not specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: excellent tip @Janne, thankyou! After ssh -X, if I run "dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY" then at last gnome-terminal starts quickly. (Still problems if more than one session on the machine of course)

Comment: Also "systemctl --user import-environment --all" from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243696/139357

Comment: This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

30 seconds sounds an awful lot like DNS timeout.

Update the question with:

```
time ssh localhost echo
time ssh -YC user@remote echo
time ssh -YC localhost gnome-calculator
```

My guess is that `remote` cannot make reverse lookup of your IP-address. So try adding this in `server:/etc/hosts`

```
 i.p.n.o myclient
```

where i.p.n.o is your clients IP address.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case. I was already using entries in `/etc/hosts` so I don't have to remember IP addresses.

Comment: Did you also do this on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, I do that on all my machines as part of OS installation.

Answer (score 1):

It makes one wonder (tongue in cheek) why the gnome programs don't execute

```
systemctl --user import-environment --all
```

and/or

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --all
```

for you...

I remember this nonsense being a problem back in the gnome bonobo days about 20 years ago, wondering like mad why my programs weren't loading up over a remote `SSH -X` session only to find when I got back home that they were all loaded on my desktop.

Now the same mistake is being made again.

Possibly this is the best fix giving a per-login dbus launcher:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346092/139357

> I added the following line to ~/.profile It sets DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable. It solved the problem for me.
>
> ```
> eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
> ```